How to create a DB transaction in the Service layer like I do in Repository?
In the code below I'm able to create a new DB transaction in a Repository method:
impl PlayerRepository for PgDatabase {
    async fn find_player_id(&self, id: &str) -> Result<String, Error> {
        let mut tx = self.pool.begin().await?;

        let _ = self.find_team_id(Some(&mut *tx), id).await?;

        let player_id = self.find_player_id(Some(&mut *tx), id).await?;

        // perform other operations within the "tx" transaction

        tx.commit().await?;

        Ok(player_id)
    }
}

I would like to be able to create that transaction in a Service method too without leaking Database details to the service layer.
Is this possible?
Code in Rust Playground

Provide a way for your PgDatabase to return a "transaction" type and implement PlayerRepository for that as well.

So you're suggesting two implementations for each method?

Please [edit] your question to include all necessary information within itself, don't put parts of it behind an external link. [so] questions MUST be self contained

You should not manage the transaction at the repository level (the repository should not know anything about which transaction it is doing the work in). You should do all the activities (commit, rollback, savepoint) related to the transaction at the business layer (service layer in your case). I would not be afraid to use the database transaction abstraction at the service layer.

Transactions are difficult to extract because they really are a persistence concern.  I have had some luck in the by encapsulating them behind a persistence-neutral interface that is independent of the database. Pass in the transaction "holder" into the repository call so that it can be added to that.
This is effectively a modification of the UnitOfWork pattern, handling just the transaction bits.   As Transactions are added to your holder, keep the list of tx objects that need to be committed, and expose a function to commit them all or roll them all back.

This seems like exactly what I have in mind, but what I haven't been able - for months - to realize! Is there any chance you could update the answer with some code?
